# Electromagnetic induction and self induction

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electromagnetic-induction

Recently i came across a concept called self-inductance. It stated that self-inductance can be considered as inertia of electricity.

Can anyone explain how this is possible

Answer (score 0):

Electrical "inertia" is an *analogy*. What really happens is this:

As electricity begins flowing through an inductor (which is a coil of wire), that current flow performs work by creating a magnetic field in the space surrounding the inductor. Increases in the flow rate of the current create increases in the strength of the magnetic field, and since those changes require the performance of work, the inductor resists the changes as it extends the field, storing energy in it.

If the current flow is decreased, the field contracts and as it does so, the diminishing field induces a current flow in the inductor which strives to maintain the original current flow through the inductor.

The constituitive equations describing these phenomena take exactly the same form as the equations which describe the behavior of a massive object to which forces are applied. The analogue of the inertia of the mass is the inductance of the coil. The velocity of the mass is the analogue of current flow through the inductor. The energy stored in the magnetic field is the analogue of the kinetic energy of the moving mass.